# emacs --daemon starting with corrupted color scheme

Tags: emacs, elisp

When I'm starting emacs as daemon I can not read comments (their color like background). But when I'm using emacs without --daemon switch everything is ok.
How to fix that weird issue?

```
;;; Custom color scheme related configurations                                                                                                                                                               
(if (< emacs-major-version 24)
  (unless (eq system-type 'windows-nt)
    (add-to-list 'load-path "/usr/share/emacs/site-lisp/emacs-goodies-el/")
    (require 'color-theme)
    (eval-after-load "color-theme"
      '(progn
         (color-theme-initialize)
         (color-theme-hober)
         )
      )
    (add-to-list 'load-path (concat dotfiles-dir "color-theme-solarized"))
    (require 'color-theme-solarized)
    )
  (progn
    (add-to-list 'custom-theme-load-path (concat dotfiles-dir "color-theme-solarized"))
    (load-theme 'solarized-dark t)
    )
)
```

> just run emacs
>   [image]
>
> run emacs -Q
>   [image]
>
> run emacs --daemon
>   [image]

as you can see - totally different results.
and line numbers are also gone in emacs -Q and emacs --daemon cases.

To enable line numbers:

```
(global-linum-mode 1)
```

emacs version: GNU Emacs 24.4.1

Comment: More information please. Do you have the same issue when running `emacs -Q`? **Exactly which settings are you losing, and how are they configured?** It sounds similar to frame- or terminal-local settings (if such settings are evaluated only when the daemon starts then they are lost, as the frames/terminals you'll actually use are not created until you start a client. In these cases you need to arrange to evaluate settings at frame creation time).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. How I can evaluate my settings at frame creation time? I'll try to do that.

Comment: See http://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/16485/454 . This seems quite odd at first glance, though. It's not obvious to me why your configuration for linum-mode would work for a non-daemon, and not for a daemon. I'm also a bit surprised that colour themes would act differently (but maybe it depends upon the theme in question). Are you seeing any errors? Does `emacs --debug-init` trigger the debugger? Anything noteworthy in the `*Messages*` buffer?

Comment: And just to be sure, your daemon *is* actually starting successfully, yes? And you're connecting to the server you think you're connecting to? (i.e. you're not just connecting to an old server which is still running old settings?) Make sure you're using `M-x kill-emacs` to kill the server before starting a new one. Or else run it like `emacs --daemon=foo` and then `emacsclient --socket-name=foo` for some `foo` which you definitely haven't used before (and of course `kill-emacs` when you're done with that).